# Weighted Probability in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability

I am trying to simulate a game in Python, given these probabilities how do I program it so it gives me a list of how many time each person wins from a total of 10 games?

The probability of A winning is  0.416667
The probability of B winning is  0.583333

Comment: It's not a python problem, it's a Mathematics problem. Solve it first in Maths, and convert it to python.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question, but A would win `10*0.416667=4.16667 times` and B would win `10*0.583333=5.83333 times`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
for x in range(0, 9):
    if expression(random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) < 0.416667):
        print "A wins"
    else:
        print "B wins"
```

If it has to be really exact this is not a good idea though since the bounderies are not handled correctly.

Comment: Can both players win?
Must either win?

Comment: Because the probabilities sum up to one, I assumed it is either A wins or B wins. No ties. So my solution is only valid under this assumption.